# My "full width" footer has a frame?

Tags: css, footer

I've looked through stackoverflow and a few other forums and haven't had any luck figuring out why I'm getting a frame around my footer? I'm trying for a full-width footer (http://www.tamararenwick.com/test/template.php), and have it mostly working, except for about a 10px wrap around the footer. Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong? I would really appreciate another (more experienced) set of eyes. Thanks!

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */


body {
 background-image: url(/test/assets/images/background.jpg);
 background-repeat: repeat;
}

#container {
 width: 860px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

/* navigation */

#nav,
#logo,
#contact {
 float: left;
}

#logo {
 padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
 width: 80px;
}

#nav {
 padding: 0px 50px 0px 0px;
 width: 450px;
}

#contact {
 padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
 width: 200px;
 text-align: right;
}


#nav p {
 font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
 font-size: 1em;
 color: #663366;
}

#contact a {
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
 font-size: 0.8em;
 color: #663366;
}

#contact a:hover    {
  color: #994d99;
  text-decoration: underline;
}


.menu,
.selected   {
 float: left;
 padding: 0px 50px 0px 0px;
}

.menu li,
.selected li  {
 list-style-type: none;
}

.menu li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
 font-size: 1.3em;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #663366;
}

.selected li a  {
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
 font-size: 1.3em;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #994d99;
}

.menu li a:hover,
.selected li a:hover    {
  color: #994d99;
}



/* home */

#home {
 margin-top: 65px;
}

#homeColOne, #homeColTwo, #homeColThree {
 float: left;
}

#homeColOne, #homeColTwo {
 width: 280px;
 margin-right: 60px;
}

#homeColThree {
 width: 280px;

}


/* inside */

#inside {
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 margin-top: 10px;
 padding: 20px 20px;
}

#columnOne, #columnTwo, #columnThree {
 float: left;
 }

#columnOne {
 min-height: 300px;
 width: 150px;
 padding-left: 0px;
 padding-right: 20px;
 padding-top: 20px;
 background: url("/test/assets/images/background-col1.jpg") no-repeat;
 background-position: top right;
}

#columnTwo {
 width: 440px;
 padding-left: 20px;
 padding-right: 20px; 
}

#columnThree {
 min-height: 300px;
 width: 150px;
 padding-left: 20px;
 padding-right: 0px;
 padding-top: 20px;
 background: url("/test/assets/images/background-col3.jpg") no-repeat;
 background-position: top left;
}


/* column one */

#columnOne .sidebar-contact, 
#columnOne .sidebar-blog,
#columnOne .sidebar-about,
#columnOne .sidebar-social,
#columnOne .sidebar-testimonials,
#columnOne .sidebar-nav, 
#columnOne .sidebar-work {
 padding: 0px 0px 40px 0px;
}


#columnOne h2 {
 font-family: "Eras Bold ITC", Verdana, sans-serif;
 font-size: 1em;
 color: #66334D;
}

#columnOne h2 a {
 color: #66334D;
 text-decoration: none;
}

#columnOne h2 a:hover {
 color: #994D99;
}

#columnOne h2 a:active {
 color: #994D99;
}


/* column one - side nav */

#columnOne .sidebar-nav ul {
 display: block;
 border-top: 1px solid #E0D5EA;
 width: 140px;
 padding-left: 0px;
 padding-right: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#columnOne .sidebar-nav ul li {
 font: 12px Arial;
 background-color: #4D3366;
 color: #e1e1e1;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #E0D5EA;
 padding: 10px;
 list-style: none;
}

#columnOne .sidebar-nav ul li a {
 color: #FFF;
 text-decoration: none;
}

#columnOne .sidebar-nav ul li a:hover {
 color: #FFF;
 text-decoration: underline;
}


/* column one - testimonials */

#columnOne .sidebar-testimonials ul {
 border-top: 0px;
 width: 130px;
 padding-left: 10px;
}

#columnOne .sidebar-testimonials ul li {
 background-color: none;
 border-bottom: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 list-style: none;
}

#columnOne .sidebar-testimonials ul li a {
 color: #212121;
 text-decoration: none;
}

#columnOne .sidebar-testimonials ul li a:hover {
 color: #994D99;
}


/* column two */

#columnTwo p {
 font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
 font-size: 0.9em;
 color: #333333;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 line-height: 22px;
}

#columnTwo b {
 font-weight: bold;
}

/* column two headers */

#columnTwo h1 {
 font-family: "Eras Bold ITC", Verdana, sans-serif;
 font-size: 1.8em;
 color: #66334D;
}

#columnTwo h2 {
 font-family: "Eras Bold ITC", Verdana, sans-serif;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 color: #66334D;
}

#columnTwo h3 {
 font-family: "Eras Bold ITC", Verdana, sans-serif;
 font-size: 1.3em;
 color: #66334D;
}

#columnTwo h4 {
 font-family: "Eras Bold ITC", Verdana, sans-serif;
 font-size: 1.1em;
 color: #66334D;
}

#columnTwo h5 {
 font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 1em;
 color: #333333;
}


/* column two hyperlinks */

#columnTwo a:link {
 color: #663366;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: bold;
}
#columnTwo a:visited {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #663366;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#columnTwo a:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
 color: #994D99;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#columnTwo a:active {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #663366;
 font-weight: bold;
}


/* column two lists */

#columnTwo ul {
 border-top: 1px solid #66334D;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #66334D;
 padding: 20px 10px 20px 30px;
 list-style: circle;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 }


#columnTwo li {
 font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
 font-size: 1em;
 color: #212121;
 line-height: 20px;
}

#columnTwo .slider-wrap ul {
 border-top: none;
 border-bottom: none;
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0px;
 height: 260px;
 margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
}
 

#columnTwo ol {
 border-top: 1px solid #66334D;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #66334D;
 padding: 20px 10px 20px 30px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 }


/* column three */

#columnThree .sidebar-contact, 
#columnThree .sidebar-blog,
#columnThree .sidebar-about,
#columnThree .sidebar-social,
#columnThree .sidebar-testimonials,
#columnThree .sidebar-work {
 padding: 0px 0px 40px 0px;
}

#columnThree p {
 padding: 0px;
}

#columnThree h2 {
 font-family: "Eras Bold ITC", Verdana, sans-serif;
 font-size: 1em;
 color: #66334D;
}

#columnThree h2 a {
 color: #66334D;
 text-decoration: none;
}

#columnThree h2 a:hover {
 color: #994D99;
}

#columnThree h2 a:active {
 color: #994D99;
}


/* button - small */

#columnOne .smallbutton,
#columnThree .smallbutton {
   border-top: 1px solid #994d99;
   background: #663366;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#663366), to(#653366));
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #663366, #653366);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #663366, #653366);
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #663366, #653366);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #663366, #653366);
   padding: 3px 5px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
   -moz-border-radius: 7px;
   border-radius: 7px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   color: #ffffff;
   font-size: 0.8em;
   font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
   text-decoration: none;
   vertical-align: middle;
   }
   
#columnOne .smallbutton:link,
#columnOne .smallbutton:visited,
#columnThree .smallbutton:link,
#columnThree .smallbutton:visited {
 color: #FFFFFF;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-weight: bold;
}


#columnOne .smallbutton:hover,
#columnThree .smallbutton:hover {
   border-top-color: #ded8e2;
   background: #ded8e2;
   text-decoration:none; 
   color: #994d99;
   }
   
#columnOne .smallbutton:active,
#columnThree .smallbutton:active {
   border-top-color: #663366;
    text-decoration:none;
   background: #663366;
   }


/* button - large  */


#columnTwo .button {
   border-top: 1px solid #994d99;
   background: #663366;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#663366), to(#653366));
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #663366, #653366);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #663366, #653366);
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #663366, #653366);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #663366, #653366);
   padding: 5px 10px;
   margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
   -moz-border-radius: 7px;
   border-radius: 7px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   color: #ffffff;
   text-decoration: none;
   vertical-align: middle;
   }
  
 
#columnTwo .button:link {
 color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: bold;
}

#columnTwo .button:visited {
 color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#columnTwo .button:hover {
   border-top-color: #ded8e2;
      text-decoration: none;
   background: #ded8e2;
   color: #994d99;
   }
   
#columnTwo .button:active {
   border-top-color: #663366;
      text-decoration: none;
   background: #663366;
   }


/* footer */

#footer {
 margin-top: 30px;
 background-color: #333333;
 padding-top: 20px;
}

#footercontainer {
 width: 860px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 min-height: 200px;
 border-bottom: solid 1px #E0D5EA;
}

#footer p {
 font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
 color:#ffffff;
 font-size: 0.9em;
 line-height: 18px;
 margin: 2px;
}



#footer h2 {
 font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
 font-size: 1.3em;
 color: #E0D5EA;
 border-bottom: solid 1px #E0D5EA;
}

#footer a:link {
 color: #ffffff;
 text-decoration: none;
}


#footer a:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
 color: #994D99;
}

#footer a:active {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #ffffff;
}


#footerColOne,
#footerColTwo,
#footerColThree {
 float: left;
}

#footerColOne {
 width: 190px;
 padding: 0px 20px 50px 40px;

}

#footerColTwo {
 width: 180px;
 padding: 0px 25px 50px 35px;
}

#footerColThree {
 width: 300px;
 padding: 0px 40px 50px 30px;
}

#footerNavOne,
#footerNavTwo {
 float: left;
 width: 80px;
}


/* copyright */

#copyright {
 font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
 font-size: 0.6em;
 color: #ffffff;
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
}


.clear {
 clear: both; 
 visibility: hidden;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />


  <!-- css includes -->

<link href="/test/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

  <!-- /css includes -->


  <!-- favicon & icon includes -->


<link href="favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" /><link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />

<link href="/test/assets/images/apple-touch-icon.jpg" rel="apple-touch-icon" />
<link href="/test/assets/images/apple-touch-icon-76x76.jpg" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" />
<link href="/test/assets/images/apple-touch-icon-120x120.jpg" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" />
<link href="/test/assets/images/apple-touch-icon-152x152.jpg" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" />


  <!-- /favicon & icon includes -->

 <!-- javascript -->
    
    <script src="/test/javascript/jquery-1-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="/test/javascript/jquery.innerfade.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(
    function(){
      $('.clients').innerfade({
      speed: 1000,
      timeout: 3000,
      type: 'random',
      containerheight: '90px'
     });
     
     $('.slider').innerfade({
      speed: 1000,
      timeout: 5000,
      type: 'sequence',
      containerheight: '260px'
     });
     
      $('.testimonials').innerfade({
      speed: 1000,
      timeout: 10000,
      type: 'random',
      containerheight: '250'
     });
   });
   </script>
    
     <!--  /javascript -->
</head>

<body>
 

     <!--  footer  -->
<div class="clear"></div>
 <div id="footer">
  <div id="footercontainer">

 <!--  column one  -->  
           
         <div id="footerColOne">
 
<h2>Contact Me</h2>
<p><a href="http://www.facebook.com/tamararenwick" target="_blank"><img src="assets/images/facebook.png" width="32" height="32" alt="Tamara Renwick - Vancouver BC Marketing Consultant - on Facebook" /></a>   <a href="http://www.twitter.com/tamararenwick" target="_blank" ><img src="assets/images/twitter.png" width="32" height="32" alt="Tamara Renwick - Vancouver BC Marketing Consultant - on Twitter" /></a> <a href="http://ca.linkedin.com/in/tamararenwick/" target="_blank" ><img src="assets/images/linkedin.png" width="32" height="32" alt="Tamara Renwick - Vancouver BC Marketing Consultant - on LinkedIn" /></a> <a href="http://www.instagram.com/tamararenwick" target="_blank" ><img src="assets/images/instagram.png" width="32" height="32" alt="Tamara Renwick - Vancouver BC Marketing Consultant - on Instagram" /></a> <a rel="publisher" href="https://www.google.com/+TamaraRenwick" target="_blank"><img src="assets/images/google-plus.png" width="32" height="32" alt="Tamara Renwick - Vancouver BC Marketing Consultant - on Google+" /></a></p>
<p><a href="mailto:info@tamararenwick.com">info@tamararenwick.com</a><br />
<a href="tel:+17789981334">778.998.1334</a></p>
</div>
 <!--  /column one  --> 
    
     <!--  column two  -->   
<div id="footerColTwo">
<h2>Navigate My Site</h2>

<div id="footerNavOne">
<p><a href="blog.php">Blog</a></p>
<p><a href="blog.php">Blog</a></p>
<p><a href="blog.php">Blog</a></p>
<p><a href="blog.php">Blog</a></p></div>

<div id="footerNavTwo">
<p><a href="blog.php">Blog</a></p>
<p><a href="blog.php">Blog</a></p>
<p><a href="blog.php">Blog</a></p>
<p><a href="blog.php">Blog</a></p></div>

</div>
 <!--  /column two  -->  

 <!--  column three  --> 
<div id="footerColThree">
<h2>Read My Blog</h2>
<p>
<a href="/more-building-a-website-from-scratch">More on Building a Website from Scratch</a></p>
<p><a href="/building-a-website-from-scratch">Building a Website from Scratch</a></p>
<p><a href="/useful-marketing-websites">Useful Marketing Websites</a></p>
<p><a href="/enactus-bcit-marketing-workshop">Enactus BCIT: Marketing Workshop</a>
</p>
</div>

 <!--  /column three  -->
    
         
</div>
   <div class="clear"></div>
    <div id="copyright">&copy; Tamara Renwick 2015. All Rights Reserved.<br />
    <a href="privacy-policy.php">Privacy Policy</a> | <a href="sitemap.php">Site Map</a></div>

</div>     <!--  /footer  -->
</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS:

```
body { padding:0 !important; margin:0 !important; }
```

The problem is your `body` element has a 8px margin.

In case you are wondering where the margin is coming from, this margin is set by the browser's default stylesheet.

Comment: No. That will make the logo on top be too close to the top.

Comment: Then add a margin around the logo, is that too hard or something? The body should never have margin or padding in the first place.

Comment: No, not too hard. At least not for me. For the one asking the question it may be.  Just point that out.

Comment: Just so you know, you never want to have a margin or padding on the body element, since that's a user agent stylesheet and there isn't a standard for it. Use a css reset beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code inside the 'body' selector of your style sheet

```
margin: 0;
```

Answer (score -1):

BETTER solution on bottom in this answer.

There is a margin around your body:

```
body {
display: block;
margin: 8px;
}
```

You can add this to your css.

```
#footer {
margin-left: -8px;
margin-right: -8px;
margin-bottom: -8px;
}
```

---

Better answer:

You can also add this in stead: (BETTER)

```
body {
margin-left: 0px !important;
margin-right: 0px !important;
margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}
```